# Mosquito net smell

Tags: home, personal-care, smell, dust

Yesterday,I covered the windows of my room with a mosquito net which I purchased recently (Taped it along the windows). This managed to keep the mosquitoes away but however, the smell due to the nylon from the net is just unbearable. 
My entire seems to get a powerful dusty smell due to these particles getting suspended in air.

I'm not allergic to dust but however my nose feels rather blocked and really uncomfortable to sit in that room.

How can I get rid of the smell?  The smell is still really strong. I did clean the net before putting it on, so the smell appears to be from the net itself and not the dust particles on it.

Comment: New manufactured items often smell. Ventilate the room well and it may improve in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend washing new nets often after first purchasing because of the smell.

Answer (score 1):

Treated insect netting often contains synthetic or natural chrysanthemum odour which has proven effective deterrent for many insects in addition to the mesh physical barrier. Chrysanthemums contain Pyrethrin which is a powerful insect deterrent.

You may be sensitive to the treatment given the fabric.

Chrysanthemum derivative has been used to treat clothing as an insect deterrent for a while by the US military and gradually adopted by others as it has shown effective against mosquitoes, fleas, flies, moths, ants, and many other pests.

The product label may refer to some treatment given the fabric that you can use to troubleshoot your situation

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. thank you for your question. Most cheap mosquito nets are untreated. The smell that you are experiencing is a "plastic chemical smell" It can stink out a room, and cause discomfort when sleeping. It is hard to find answers to this. But you can find help online about removing "plastic smells" from plastic. Some ideas that you can try are:
-Direct sunlight and airing out
-Using lemon juice and soaking it - then washing it
-Using baking soda as a paste and covering it and then washing it
I am not sure if these will work - but I wouldn't use anything like vinegar or charcoal as they might create a new smell.
-Most people don't use mosquito nets because they smell.